# apache rewrite folder+query to query

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

How can I get Apache rewrite to do the following...

take a url received as:

```
domain/somename/index.php?query=1&anotherquery=2
```

and change it to:

```
domain/index.php?query=1&anotherquery=2&name=somename
```

cheers,
Omer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/index\.php$ index.php?name=$1 [QSA]
```